# Why were these self-answer comment flags declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, comment-flags

For this question—[Mockito Error Is Not Applicable for the Arguments (void)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29537574/1426891)—the original poster answered his own question in the comments immediately after posting. Via a comment I encouraged him to post his solution as a self-answer instead, which he did. I stumbled across it just now, months after the post, so I deleted my suggestion and flagged his two self-answering comments for removal. (I considered the alternative of flagging the parent post, but with only two separate low-value comments, I just flagged them individually.)

Both comment flags were declined, despite being obsolete at best. It may have been my mistake, as my justification was "self-answer was posted to comments", without mentioning that it was already posted as an actual answer.

Is there a policy reason for this, or was it just an oversight? Can moderators see a question's answers from the "flag a question comment" page?

---

**UPDATE:** I resubmitted the flags with the justification

> OP already promoted comment into self-answer.

instead of

> Self-answer was posted as a comment.

and they were both accepted properly.

Comment: If you want a moderator to do something unusual, like deleting an entire comment trail, then be sure to use a custom flag and explain why it is necessary.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It sounds like your flag description wasn't clear enough.  That someone posted an answer in comments doesn't mean that those comments should be deleted.  That an answer in comments was reposted as an answer *is* a valid reason to delete those comments.  If you flag the comment to say that it has since been posted as an answer, and is now obsolete, I'd fully expect the comment to be deleted.

Comment: Thanks. That's more-or-less what I had expected, but I'd also imagined that it would have been easy to see that that was the case without typing it out.

Comment: @JeffBowman When mods are handling a flag they're going to look at the reason you flagged the post, see if it applies, and see if that merits an action.  If it doesn't, they aren't going to look for all of the other potential problems it could have to see if they need to be addressed.  It's just not practical given the number of flags they get.  If you want them to take an action, you need to actually explain why its merited.

Comment: @JeffBowman - In addition to what Servy said, we often get a lot of mistaken flags stating things like "this comment should be an answer" that we have to decline (we can't convert comments to answers, and we're not going to delete the comments). Your flags at first glance could have been read like that, which might be why they were declined.